# How to properly load jQuery plugins on 3rd party website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, widget

I'm building a widget that uses a few jQuery plugins to work.

It is deployed via:

```
<script src="http://example.com/widget"></script>
<div id="widget"></div>
```

And the fetched script looks like this:

```
(function() {
  var jQuery;
  // Look for jQuery on page; if there, use it, otherwise fetch it
  if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '2.1.3') {
    loadScript("//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js", scriptLoadHandler);
  } else {
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    loadExternalLibraries();
    main();
  }

  // Fetch 3rd party libraries from server
  function loadExternalLibraries() {
    <% widget_javascripts.each do |filename| %>
      var url = "//example.com/widget/javascripts/" + "<%= filename %>";
      loadScript(url, function() {
        console.log("Added " + "<%= filename%>");
      });
    <% end %>
  }

  function loadScript(url, callback) {
    /* Load script from url and calls callback once it's loaded */
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    scriptTag.setAttribute("src", url);
    if (typeof callback !== "undefined") {
      if (scriptTag.readyState) {
        /* For old versions of IE */
        scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () { 
          if (this.readyState === 'complete' || this.readyState === 'loaded') {
            callback();
          }
        };
      } else {
        scriptTag.onload = callback;
      }
    }
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptTag);
  }

  function scriptLoadHandler() {
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    loadExternalLibraries();      
    main();
  }

  function main() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#widget').plugin1();
    });
  }
})();
```

jQuery seems to load fine, but `$('#widget').plugin1()` returns the classic `TypeError: $(...).plugin1 is not a function`.

So I tried following this post (http://alexmarandon.com/articles/widget-jquery-plugins/) and wrapped the plugin in another function and passed the local `jQuery` variable to it like so:

```
// Plugin1 code
function initPlugin1(jQuery) {
  (function ($) {
    # plugin code here
  }(jQuery));
}

// modified loadExternalLibraries function
function loadExternalLibraries() {
  % widget_javascripts.each do |filename| %>
    var url = "//example.com/widget/javascripts/" + "<%= filename %>";
    loadScript(url, function() {
      initPlugin1(jQuery);
    });
  <% end %>
}
```

In addition to being reminded that `initPlugin1 is not defined` for every other plugin library fetched, I'm still getting the original `TypeError` error.

Assuming I have 4-5 such plugins to fetch (with none to all possibly minified as well), am I approaching this problem in the correct manner?

Comment: There is a great article how to solve this problem http://developers.livechatinc.com/blog/always-use-closures-in-your-javascript-app/